# String replacement layering

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, ms-access

I am not sure how best to title this question. I am working on implementing essentially a throwaway program to do some extremely custom and specific searching & replacement through a batch of microsoft access databases. I'm running into an issue where some tokens are part of the search or replacement portion of a larger token. Example:

```
    Horse:Battery -> HorseBattery
    Horse:Battery:Staple -> HorseBatteryStaple
    Correct:Horse:Battery -> CorrectHorseBattery
```

As you can see, the order in which these replacements are performed could affect the outcome. This is a poor and incomplete snapshot of the larger problem.

Is there a specific algorithm for applying multiple string search & replace operations against a given input text in such a way that no overlapping is performed?

Comment: please include some code of what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: I can't for two reasons: 1) it's 800+ lines of mostly procedural code that is tightly bound to the specific task (our in-house Access databases), and 2) it's proprietary and I can't share it in a public setting. If you REALLY want some code, here it is: s = s.Replace(r.SearchToken, r.ReplacementToken);

Comment: if you can't share your code, we can't help you. it's like trying to fix a car from the outside. Remove the proprietary elements, and post the minimum block required to make the question answerable.

Comment: This is an algorithm question not a code question.

Comment: cathode, i think you need a better example, or a better problem statement to get some decent help. it's not very clear what the search token is, or what the replacement is.

Comment: I suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, assuming you have your `tokens` as `strings`

```
string[] dataAccess = {"Horse:Battery", "Horse:Battery:Staple", "Correct:Horse:Battery"};
foreach (var value in dataAccess)
{
 var newValue = string.Empty;
 var values = value.Split(':');
 newValue = values.Aggregate(newValue, (current, word) => current + word);
}
```